# Почему не считывают все данные с файла?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Students
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char adress[40];
    char gender[15];
    int numberofgroup;
};
 
 
bool ReadFile(Students*& arr_Students, int& size)
{
    arr_Students = new Students[100];
    size = 0;
 
    ifstream fin("Students.txt");
    while (fin >> arr_Students[size].name)
    {
        fin >> arr_Students[size].surname;
 
        fin.ignore();
        fin.getline(arr_Students[size].adress, std::size(arr_Students[size].adress));
 
        fin >> arr_Students[size].gender;
        fin >> arr_Students[size].numberofgroup;
 
 
        ++size;
        if (size >= 100)
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
void print(Students* arr_Students, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr_Students[i].name << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].surname << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].adress << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].gender << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].numberofgroup << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    string streets;
 
    cout << "Введите улицу: ";
    cin >> streets;
    int n = 0;
 
 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        string tempAddress = arr_Students[i].adress;
        if (tempAddress.find(streets) != string::npos) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Количество студентов, живущих на указанном с клавиатуры улице:" << n;
}
 
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
 
    bool ReadFile(Students * &arr_Students, int& size);
    void print(Students * arr_Students, int size);
 
    int size;
    Students* arr_Students;
    if (ReadFile(arr_Students, size))
        print(arr_Students, size);
    else
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот файл

> Артем
> Панасюк
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Ленина, 44
> Мужчина
> 3
> Марина
> Броваренко
> Город Винница, ул. Тараса Шевченко, 12
> женщина
> 1
> Евгения
> Романченко
> Город Луганск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 32
> женщина
> 2
> Ярослав
> Шевченко
> Город Кировоград, ул. 50 лет Октября, 31
> Мужчина
> 4
> Bьячеслав
> Романченко
> Город Черкассы, ул. Космонавта Попова, 57
> Мужчина
> 5
> Екатерина
> среда
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 94
> женщина
> 7
> Мирослав
> Панасюк
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 80
> Мужчина
> 6
> Ольга
> Лысенко
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 76
> женщина
> 8
> Александр
> Таращук
> Город Луганск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 31
> Мужчина
> 9
> Ярослав
> Васильев
> Город Луганск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 25
> Мужчина
> 10
> Екатерина
> среда
> Город Черкассы, ул. Космонавта Попова, 32
> женщина
> 11
> Назар
> Шевчук
> Город Черкассы, ул. Космонавта Попова, 21
> Мужчина
> 13
> Виталий
> среда
> Город Кировоград, ул. 50 лет Октября, 21
> Мужчина
> 12
> Татьяна
> Захарчук
> Город Кировоград, ул. 50 лет Октября, 20
> женщина
> 14
> Ярослав
> Шинкаренко
> Город Херсон, ул. Ивана Франко, 12
> Мужчина
> 15
> Игорь
> Пономарчук
> Город Херсон, ул. Ивана Франко, 21
> Мужчина
> 16
> Константин
> Пономарчук
> Город Донецк, ул. Волкова, 99
> Мужчина
> 17
> Андрей
> Захарчук
> Город Львов, ул. Тараса Шевченко, 83
> Мужчина
> 18
> Елена
> Павлюк
> Город Черновцы, ул. Михаила Грушевского, 42
> женщина
> 19
> Елизавета
> Романченко
> Город Киев, ул. Леси Украинский, 45
> женщина
> 20
> Иосиф
> Боднаренко
> Город Киев, ул. Леси Украинский, 21
> Мужчина
> 21
> Ярослав
> Крамарчук
> Город Тернополь, ул. Гагарина, 54
> Мужчина
> 22
> Тамара
> Таращук
> Город Тернополь, ул. Гагарина, 31
> женщина
> 23
> Инна
> Кравченко
> Город Сумы, ул. Михаила Грушевского, 30
> женщина
> 24
> Игорь
> Кравченко
> Город Сумы, ул. Михаила Грушевского, 12
> женщина
> 25
> Виталий
> Лысенко
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Богдана Хмельницкого, 1
> Мужчина
> 26
> Денис
> Витрук
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Богдана Хмельницкого, 7
> Мужчина
> 27
> Даниил
> Крамарчук
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Независимости, 94
> Мужчина
> 28
> Валентин
> Янович
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Независимости, 15
> Мужчина
> 29
> Артем
> Петренко
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Независимости, 76
> Мужчина
> 30

Что выводит:

> Артем
> Панасюк
> Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Ленина, 44
> Мужчина
> 3
> Марина
> Броваренко
> Город Винница, ул. Тараса Шевченко, 12
> женщина
> 1
> Евгения
> Романченко
> Город Луганск, ул. Генерала Жадова, 3
> -842 150 451
> Введите улицу:

Comment: дебагером пользовались?

Comment: `getline` читает всё до конца строки. Вместе с гендером и номером группы. Ну или пока есть место в массиве.

Comment: как тогда его сделать?

Comment: Теперь так выводит
Артем
Панасюк
Город Ивано-Франковск
ул.
0

Введите улицу:

Comment: @EOF что-то не помогло

Comment: Да, а немного ошибся. Показалось, что запятая идет после адреса.

Comment: @EOF а как тогда надо?

Comment: В любом случае `Город Ивано-Франковск, ул. Богдана Хмельницкого, 1` не поместится в массив на 40 символов. Вот если бы использовали `string` в структуре, то было бы намного меньше головной боли.

Comment: как сделать через string чтобы все работало?

Comment: @EOF как сделать через string чтобы все работало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот Ваш код, но с использованием `string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Students
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    string adress;
    string gender;
    int numberofgroup;
};
 
bool ReadFile(Students*& arr_Students, int& size)
{
    arr_Students = new Students[100];
    size = 0;
 
    ifstream fin("Students.txt");
    while (fin >> arr_Students[size].name)
    {
        fin >> arr_Students[size].surname;
        fin.ignore();

        getline(fin, arr_Students[size].adress);

        fin >> arr_Students[size].gender;
        fin >> arr_Students[size].numberofgroup;
 
        ++size;
        if (size >= 100)
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

void print(Students* arr_Students, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr_Students[i].name << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].surname << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].adress << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].gender << endl;
        cout << arr_Students[i].numberofgroup << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    string streets;
 
    cout << "Введите улицу: ";
    getline(cin, streets);
    int n = 0;
 
 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // Здесь тоже изменения: временный обьект уже не нужен
        if (arr_Students[i].adress.find(streets) != string::npos) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Количество студентов, живущих на указанном с клавиатуры улице:" << n;
}
 
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
 
    bool ReadFile(Students * &arr_Students, int& size);
    void print(Students * arr_Students, int size);
 
    int size;
    Students* arr_Students;
    if (ReadFile(arr_Students, size))
        print(arr_Students, size);
    else
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И каким образом после `getline()` будут введены правильные `.gender` и `.numberofgroup`?

Comment: Комментарий в коде о подобном формате исходных данных очень бы не помешал