# Как работает эта функция(что она делает?)

Tags: c++, c++11

```
bool ReadFile(Students*& arr_Students, int& size)
{
    arr_Students = new Students[100];
    size = 0;

    ifstream fin("Students.txt");
    while (fin >> arr_Students[size].name)
    {
        fin >> arr_Students[size].surname;
        fin.ignore();

        getline(fin, arr_Students[size].adress);

        fin >> arr_Students[size].gender;
        fin >> arr_Students[size].numberofgroup;

        ++size;
        if (size >= 100)
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: функция читает из файла данные по студентам

Comment: читает данные с файла о студентах - имя/фамилию, пол и  номер группы. Больше сотни читать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

из файла считывает слово, слово, строку, слово слово (т.е. скорее всего это 3 строки) и записывает их в текущую ячейку массива студентов

где студент - это структура с именем, фамилией, адресом, полом и номером группы

если вдруг информации в файле больше чем на 100 студентов - прекращаем считывать из файла и выходим не закрыв файл (потому что мама не учила хорошим манерам)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215398/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0

Comment: ошибся с 3 строками :(

Comment: для чего fin.ignore и getline?

Comment: @Zhinar для чего fin.ignore и getline?

Comment: По идее там всё можно заметить на `getline`, кроме ввода числа конечно.

Comment: @EOF для чего fin.ignore и getline?

Comment: Vanyipz, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Comment: Там локальный объект, он сам себя закроет после выхода.

Comment: @Vanyipz,   `fin.ignore()`  тут пропускает один символ после введенного surname. Т.е. если адрес идет с новой строки, то после surname должен идти непосредственно '\n' (никаких пробелов в конце). Либо адрес должен быт в одной строке с surname. // неудачный формат входных данных